# Comparing two groups' answers to 10 Likert questions

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, likert

I’m having two different groups complete the same survey (they differ in terms of their profession) consisting of 10, 5-point Likert style questions asking how much they agree or disagree that a given factor influences their decision to take a certain action. I need to ascertain whether the groups differ or agree on how much they value those given factors, and am not sure after reading a few similar questions here if a t-test just examining each individual item between the groups is best, or if another approach would be better.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Sointu gave some good suggestions.

Another idea is to try to account for "person effects" by running some sort of ordinal multilevel model with "score" as the dependent variable, "item" as the independent variable, and "person" as a random effect. That might be overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do the 10 questions all measure distinctively different 10 things? If possibly not, you could take the questions that measure the same thing and average responses to these questions and analyze group differences in those averages.

If you have enough participants you could run a factor analysis or a principal component analysis for the items and use the results to determine which items you average. If you have theoretical reasons to believe some items measure the same thing, you can check their reliability and if that's adequate you can average them on theoretical grounds.

If you end up running separate t-tests for the 10 items, use some kind of p-value adjustment because you are running 10 tests on the same dataset.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with description and exploration.

Despite some dogma that only medians are justified, means of Likert items can pick up more information. Who thinks that 1,1,2,3,3 and 2,2,2,3,4 can only be summarized adequately by the same median 2?

If that is a step too far for researchers, or for what may be feared from mentors or reviewers, summaries that don't go beyond what is directly implied by the data have flavour like % saying 4 or 5 MINUS % saying 1 or 2. A graph with such summaries for 10 items and 2 groups could be a good start.